# Taxonomies specific to Page attribute template

Tags: custom-taxonomy, page-template

Edit 2:

So having worked a lot on this I have come along way and have a solution that indeed allows me to filter taxonomies by page template, however it isn't very DRY or very flexible. Ideally I would like to make this even more flexible so that I can use it to link several templates and taxonomies.

The problem I ran into was that if I define the taxonomies array outside of the function it doesn't work even though I am passing it through as an argument. Im having one of those days where I have looked at this code for so long that I cant see the wood for the trees. Can anyone possibly help by giving some tips on refactoring this to make it more DRY.

Thanks.

```
function create_taxonomy($name,$type = 'page') {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        strtolower( str_replace(' ','-', $name ) ),
        $type,
        array(
            'label'     => __( $name ),
            'sort'      => true,
            'args'      => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
            'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => strtolower( str_replace(' ','-', $name ) ) )
        )
    );

    //return strtolower(str_replace(' ','-', $name));

}


function case_study_taxonomy($template,$taxonomies){

    $current_template = get_post_meta($_GET['post'], '_wp_page_template', true);

    if ($current_template == $template){

        $taxonomies = array(

            create_taxonomy('Project Type'),
            create_taxonomy('System Finishes'),
            create_taxonomy('Client'),
            create_taxonomy('System Installer'),
            create_taxonomy('Architect'),
            create_taxonomy('Partnering Contractor'),
        );

        foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy){

            add_action( 'admin_menu', $taxonomy );

        }

    }   

}

case_study_taxonomy('template-case-study.php',$taxonomies);
```

Comment: Are you only using the page heirarchy for generating the menu or does it serve other purposes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your explanation of how things are set up, or if it's the best way to go about what you're trying to do, but to answer your specific question-

the selected template for a page is stored in post meta under the key `_wp_page_template`, you can check this key to see if your case study template is selected, otherwise use [`remove_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) to hide the taxonomy for all other pages.

Comment: Thanks you have pointed me in the right direction to answering my question with _wp_page_template